# Grouping and building intervals of data in R and useful visualization

Tags: r, intervals

I have some data extracted via HIVE. In the end we are talking of csv with around 500 000 rows. I want to plot them after grouping them in intervals.

Beside the grouping it's not clear how to visualize the data. Since we are talking about low spends and sometimes a high frequency I'm not sure how to handle this problem.

Here is just an overview via head(data)

```
userid64            spend           freq
575033023245123     0.00924205      489
12588968125440467   0.00037         2
13830962861053825   0.00168         1
18983461971805285   0.001500366     333
25159368164208149   0.00215         1
32284253673482883   0.001721303     222
33221593608613197   0.00298         709
39590145306822865   0.001785281     11
45831636009567401   0.00397         654
71526649454205197   0.000949978     1
78782620614743930   0.00552         5
```

I want to group the data in intervals. So I want an extra columns indicating the groups. The first group should contain all data with an frequency (called freq) between 1 and 100. The second group should contain all rows where there entries have a frequency between 101 and 200... and so on.

The result should look like

```
userid64            spend           freq        group
575033023245123     0.00924205      489         5
12588968125440467   0.00037         2           1
13830962861053825   0.00168         1           1
18983461971805285   0.001500366     333         3
25159368164208149   0.00215         1           1
32284253673482883   0.001721303     222         2
33221593608613197   0.00298         709         8
39590145306822865   0.001785281     11          1
45831636009567401   0.00397         654         7
71526649454205197   0.000949978     1           1
78782620614743930   0.00552         5           1
```

Is there a nice and gentle art to get this? I need this grouping for upcoming plots. I want to do visualization for all intervals to get an overview regarding the spend. If you have any ideas for the visualization please let me know. I thought I should work with boxplots.

Comment: An alternative to using integer division is `cut`: `as.numeric(cut(x$freq, (0 : 10) * 100))`. Beware that this hard-codes the upper bound; it would be better to determine the upper bound programmatically, at which point it becomes easier to just use the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group `freq` for every 100 units, you can try `ceiling` function in `base R`

```
ceiling(df$freq / 100)

#[1] 5 1 1 4 1 3 8 1 7 1 1
```

where `df` is your dataframe.